# xquery get odd/even node results

Tags: xquery

```
<tr><td>garblegarble</td></tr>
<tr><td>goold</td></tr>
<tr><td>garblegfhjgarble</td></tr>
<tr><td>platinum</td></tr>
<tr><td>garblfgjfegarble</td></tr>
<tr><td>diamnodz</td></tr>
....
```

How can I select only TRs 2,4,6,8,10... in other word the even results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
//tr[position() mod 2 = 0]
```